# Difference between Feedback and Product improvement program

Tags: 8.1, feedback

I recently noted that there are two ways to send feedback (telemetry data) to Microsoft. They are :

1. Feedback : Located in *Settings->Feedback*

[image: Feedback settings]

2. Product Improvement program : Located in *Settings->Rate Us->Participate*

[image: Product improvement program settings]

I could not find the difference between the two services. I don't understand the need for Microsoft to give me two options to share my telemetry data.

Could someone list what data is shared by these programs(separately)? And **what is the difference between these two**?

Comment: Have you checked the "More information online" link and the "Privacy statement"? Perhaps one is from Microsoft and one from the OEM (Nokia etc).

Comment: @Thomas Yes. Privacy statement from *Feedback* led to Windows phone privacy statement and *More information online* led to Microsoft's privacy statement. They both state what data is collected and how it is used by MS in **general** i.e all of MS services. They **fail to provide me the details specific to these programs**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In a Nutshell :**

The Product Improvement program is related to **OEM** and the Feedback is related to **Windows OS**.

**The long story :**

The Product Improvement Program seems to be the continuation of Nokia Improvement program.

All the official links to Nokia Improvement program were removed. However I was able to find articles on [knowyourmobile.com](http://www.knowyourmobile.com/nokia/19021/how-perform-first-time-setup-your-nokia-lumia-920), [geeksquad](http://www.geeksquad.co.uk/articles/nokia-lumia-830-manual-user-setup-guide) and [ee.co.uk](http://ee.co.uk/help/phones-and-device/nokia/nokia-lumia-625/nokia-lumia-625-internet-and-applications/nokia-lumia-625---activate-your-nokia-through-the-setup-wizard) that describe Nokia Improvement program as a part of setting up a new Lumia.

The purpose of Nokia Improvement Program as quoted in this [article](http://www.knowyourmobile.com/nokia/19021/how-perform-first-time-setup-your-nokia-lumia-920) is,

> The next page will allow you to opt in or out of Nokia's ‘Improvement
>   Program,' essentially choosing whether or not to allow the phone to
>   feed information to Nokia which it can use to develop new or existing
>   services.

There is no official reference that older Nokia improvement program is the current Product improvement program. However it is safe to assume that they are same since,

1. Microsoft bought Nokia.
2. The older links to Nokia Improvement program such as below ones from search results open Microsoft's [privacy statement](https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-gb/privacystatement).
   [image]
   [image]
3. Their visuals are similar.

[image: Comparrisiion - Nokia and Product improvement program]

So, Microsoft has two option to collect telemetry data as one is related to OEM and the other one is related to OS. It is worthy to note that Product Improvement Program was also present in my Asha smartphone. It appears what @[Thomas](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/979/thomas) suggested in comments holds true.

**References** :

1. [Perform first time setup Lumia 920 - Knowyourmobile](http://www.knowyourmobile.com/nokia/19021/how-perform-first-time-setup-your-nokia-lumia-920)
2. [Nokia Lumia 830 user setup guide - Geeksquas](http://www.geeksquad.co.uk/articles/nokia-lumia-830-manual-user-setup-guide)
3. [Nokia Lumia 625 Setup Wizard - ee.co.uk](http://ee.co.uk/help/phones-and-device/nokia/nokia-lumia-625/nokia-lumia-625-internet-and-applications/nokia-lumia-625---activate-your-nokia-through-the-setup-wizard)